# Is there a formal specification for Ethereum transactions?

Tags: transactions

The transaction object in Ethereum must have a number of fields, ie, nonce, gasPrice, to, data, value, gasLimit. In the Ethereum yellow paper, it specifies these fields, but doesn't go into specifics. For example, it just says nonce must be a scalar value.

Is there a more specific specification? Like, must nonce be a u16, u128, u256, or some other scalar value? Does it matter?

Answer (score 0):

The official client [go-ethereum](https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum) is a great source of information if you don't find what you are looking for in the papers.

You can find the definition of the tx data [here](https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/blob/d6f49bf764c48e9415b168e701b6dc26566a675c/core/types/transaction.go#L71) where it states that nonce is of type `uint64`. You can check for almost every other field that you are interested in at the same place.

Comment: Hmm, I guess then there is no specific scalar value? I noticed that a separate library uses U256 as the type for nonce.